# rotate text -90deg vertically center align right with unknown text length

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

I'm trying to rotate text -90, align it to the right edge of my parent div, and center vertically.

```
<div>
 <p class="verticaltext">
   some text
 </p>
<div>
```

```
.verticaltext {
    top: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    position: absolute; 
}

div {
    position: relative;
}
```

The issue is the combination of positioning to the right and vertical center.

Left 100% allows me to position the text to the right regardless of the length of the text but this requires origin bottom left.

Problem is top 50% and translate y -50% combined with origin bottom left places the bottom left of the text on the vertical center, I want the center of the text aligned with the vertical center. If I set the origin to center I can get vertical center but it screws up my placement to the right with left 100%.

Comment: read the duplicate until the end. You will also find a link to an article detailing all the cases

Comment: this works great (in theory) thanks for the link, i'm realizing the problem has to do with the parent div which is a javascript slider I think the js is screwing up the positioning. I'll need to do some troubleshooting.